# advanced custom fields if field has value show main div

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

```
<?php if( get_field('packaging_details','port','lead_time') ): ?>
<div class="prd-overview-list">    
<h3>Packaging & Delivery</h3>
    <ul>
        <?php if( get_field('packaging_details') ): ?><li><p>Packaging Details</p> <p><span><?php the_field( 'packaging_details' ); ?></span></p></li><?php endif; ?>
        <?php if( get_field('port') ): ?><li><p>Port</p> <p><span><?php the_field( 'port' ); ?></span></p></li><?php endif; ?>
        <?php if( get_field('lead_time') ): ?><li><p>Lead Time</p> <p><span><?php the_field( 'lead_time' ); ?></span></p></li><?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
</div><?php endif; ?>
```

i want if all 3 fields are empty, hide full div. and when any field have value, show full div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below and let me know if any query.

```
<?php if( get_field('packaging_details') || get_field('port') || get_field('lead_time')): ?>
        <div class="prd-overview-list">    
        <h3>Packaging & Delivery</h3>
            <ul>
                <?php if( get_field('packaging_details') ): ?><li><p>Packaging Details</p> <p><span><?php the_field( 'packaging_details' ); ?></span></p></li><?php endif; ?>
                <?php if( get_field('port') ): ?><li><p>Port</p> <p><span><?php the_field( 'port' ); ?></span></p></li><?php endif; ?>
                <?php if( get_field('lead_time') ): ?><li><p>Lead Time</p> <p><span><?php the_field( 'lead_time' ); ?></span></p></li><?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
    </div><?php endif; ?>
```

Hope it will help you !

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: sir, what about if there is more then 10 fields?

Comment: You have to add each and every field condition :)

Comment: it's showing error when i am adding more

Comment: Please show me your latest code with more fields

Comment: sir please check here:- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/321849/advanced-custom-fields-if-field-has-value-show-main-div-more-then-10-fields